# Record audio compatible to play on windows

Tags: iphone, m4a

I need to record audio file in such a format which can be played on windows system also. I am using SpeakHere example's class AudioRecorder to record the audio but file recorded by this doesn't play on windows.

So what format flag should be used to achieve this compatibility. Currently my settings for format flags are as follows:

```
audioFormat.mSampleRate = 44100.0;
audioFormat.mFormatID   = formatID;//kAudioFormatLinearPCM
audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
audioFormat.mFormatFlags    = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger |  kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2;
audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame  = 2;
```